# JavaScript Create Table and filling with an array content

Tags: javascript, arrays, insert

I need to create a table in JS which have 3 cells in the first row and in the rest (20 rows) 4 column.
How should I do it work properly if I want to fill the rows from an array value?
So I have myArray[0, 1, 2, 3...] and those values need to insert into the table starting with the second row. (First is like header row)

```
        const apptid_divs11 = [...document.querySelectorAll('.apptSearchResultSelected')];
    const apptid_set11 = new Set(apptid_divs11.map(div => div.textContent.trim().split('#')[0]))
```

The apptid_set11 values needs to go to the table, but the size of the array is always changing

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to create the table in the right format, because the second and third columns should have just 1 cell in the header row.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't detailed.  The following is an example which you can use as a home base

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
      <thead>
        <th>H1</th>
        <th>H2</th>
        <th colspan="2">H3</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
      let myArrayData = Array.from(Array(20), (x, i) => i);

      let rows = "";

      for (let rowData of myArrayData) {
        rows += `
          <tr>
            <td>${rowData}</td>
            <td>${rowData}</td>
            <td>${rowData}</td>
            <td>${rowData}</td>
            
          </tr>
        `;
      }

      document.querySelector("table tbody").innerHTML = rows;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```